# Token based authentication Ticket parts

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am using token based authentication and i'm new in this topic. I have this question: what's the difference between adding claims and adding properties in 
`AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity,properties)`. So in this example:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {
                        "as:client_id", (context.ClientId == null) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId
                    },
                    {
                        "userName", context.UserName
                    }
                });
 var ticket =new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
```

What's the difference between adding userName in claims and in ticket properties?

Answer (score 1):

Claims are primarily information about the user and may be used as part of Authorization decisions. Properties are used to flow implementation details during the Authentication process.